# Devise Sign Up Freeze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am getting a strange error with Devise on my Ruby on Rails app. When proceeding to the default Sign-Up form, after entering the email, and password field and then pressing sign-up, the button becomes unclickable 
and then nothing happens.

Previous Users have been successfully registered via this method, so I can confirm it did work previously. I have since not registered any new users in many months.

Heroku logs don't show any activity except for getting the sign-up page.

[image: Sign Up Image]

> 2016-10-12T13:34:23.799746+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET
>   "/users/sign_up" for 101.164.74.67 at 2016-10-13 00:34:23 +1100
>   2016-10-12T13:34:23.801698+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
>   Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
>   2016-10-12T13:34:23.806692+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   devise/_basic_form.html.erb (2.8ms) 2016-10-12T13:34:23.807344+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.5ms)
>   2016-10-12T13:34:23.807443+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
>   2016-10-12T13:34:23.810189+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms
>   (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 2016-10-12T13:34:24.055291+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/application-fca53857b919fcfd74765023315d07a5dcd04e0903cc840513af7edff1a08efd.css" host=www.puntsquad.com request_id=aa91286f-b
>   fd8-4650-bc12-d6d9e51da3a9 fwd="101.164.74.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms
>   service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
>
> 2016-10-12T13:34:24.074652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/chartkick-f077bcf66f815b88f8d0c98ee47a985e34e82baad8e59cd59bf539b48610e20d.js"
>   host=www.puntsquad.com request_id=99ee8e9f-c1e6
>   -446b-97d9-890d25675a3f fwd="101.164.74.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133 2016-10-12T13:34:24.062979+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/application-8ca7fdc6c863cd6724872dba3750dc3ad3fc9a9ea1921a4fac1e31356e0df7ba.js"
>   host=www.puntsquad.com request_id=89d93555-31
>   c4-4276-9697-62a802a8faf5 fwd="101.164.74.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms
>   service=3ms status=304 bytes=133 2016-10-12T13:34:24.310851+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/logo-dark-text-25488e5bdfd754d5a6323b07d20d3ad45a14d4914d89fb6b079fd26a90def0a9.png" host=www.puntsquad.com request_id=21a3ebe
>   e-c828-4469-b64c-c1e78dcefeb9 fwd="101.164.74.67" dyno=web.1
>   connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
>   2016-10-12T13:34:24.333208+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/logo-842bcfb411552d5c9608dd20e5f3824023295525e43950d93b720fbf047eed82.png" host=www.puntsquad.com request_id=81224e9e-ac3b-466
>   7-a580-01991908c44b fwd="101.164.74.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms
>   service=3ms status=304 bytes=133 2016-10-12T13:34:24.343606+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ff82aeed6b9bb6701696c84d1b223d2e682eb78c89117a438ce6cfea8c498995.woff2?v=4.5.0"
>   host=www.puntsquad.com req
>   uest_id=8bf04f8a-9f14-4b90-a50a-ffe50666a70d fwd="101.164.74.67"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
>   2016-10-12T13:34:24.755694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/fontawesome-webfont-c812ddc9e475d3e65d68a6b3b589ce598a2a5babb7afc55477d59215c4a38a40.woff?v=4.5.0"
>   host=www.puntsquad.com requ
>   est_id=ac598fcc-b038-45ca-a78c-6557dc96a897 fwd="101.164.74.67"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=133
>   2016-10-12T13:34:24.995528+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/assets/fontawesome-webfont-7b5a4320fba0d4c8f79327645b4b9cc875a2ec617a557e849b813918eb733499.ttf?v=4.5.0"
>   host=www.puntsquad.com reque
>   st_id=6d8e4172-8b95-4615-8479-0e9bd83cef17 fwd="101.164.74.67"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
>   2016-10-12T13:34:25.261030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/favicon.ico" host=www.puntsquad.com
>   request_id=c2e6c575-4e49-4b09-91eb-001ea0d21bbb fwd="101.164.74.67"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms servic e=9ms status=200 bytes=228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this is because you're Strip publishable key is invalid. 
You need to obtain or re-add a valid key.
See the Stripe documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) for Setting your publishable key.

I debugged this by visiting his site, trying to register and observing the Stripe error on the browser console.

Comment: Thank you I found my problem there. My stripe api keys had not been correctly set.

Comment: No problem. Glad you sorted it out!